# Distance between points in two lists ordered by element instead of by min

Tags: r, vector, apply, geospatial, distance

I'm writing a code to track moving particles between static nodes. In each frame, the particles locate the 2 closest nodes to them, and how far they are from each. However, with the code I wrote, I'm having a hard time specifying which distance to measure when particles are close to each other. As a reproducible example:

```
 library(rgeos)
 library(ggplot)

 #nonmoving background nodes
 set.seed(5)
 nodes <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=20,ncol=2))
 colnames(nodes) <- c("X","Y")
 nodes$X <- runif(20,0,20)
 nodes$Y <- runif(20,0,20)

 ggplot(data=nodes,aes(x=X,y=Y))+
   geom_point()


 # particles first frame
 particles1 <- c(0,19,5,2,10,10,20,1,15,17)
 particles1 <- matrix(particles1,ncol=2,byrow=T)
 particles1 <- as.data.frame(particles1)

 ggplot(data=nodes,aes(x=X,y=Y))+
   geom_point()+
   geom_point(data=particles1,aes(x=V1,y=V2),col="red")
```

So we can already see here which nodes will be closest to which particles.

```
 #find 2 closest nodes to each particle
 closestnodes <- t(apply (gDistance (SpatialPoints(nodes), SpatialPoints(particles1) ,byid=T), 1, function(x) order(x,decreasing=F)[1:2]))

 # plot particles in red, closest nodes in orange
 ggplot(data=nodes,aes(x=X,y=Y))+
   geom_point()+
   geom_point(data=particles1,aes(x=V1,y=V2),col="red")+
   geom_point(data=nodes[closestnodes,],aes(x=X,y=Y),col="orange")

 #find distances to first and second closest nodes
 distances<- 
 cbind(apply(gDistance(SpatialPoints(nodes[closestnodes[,1],]),                            
 SpatialPoints(particles1),byid=T),1,min),            
 apply(gDistance(SpatialPoints(nodes[closestnodes[,2],]),
 SpatialPoints(particles1),byid=T),1,min))
```

Great, so that code all works and gives distances from each point to the two closest nodes to it, but the problem occurs when the points move closer together or share close nodes.

```
 #new particle df
 particles2 <- c(4,9.7,4,14,10,2,15,13,18,14)
 particles2 <- matrix(particles2,ncol=2,byrow=T)
 particles2 <- as.data.frame(particles2)

 #new closest nodes
 closestnodes2 <- t(apply(gDistance(SpatialPoints(nodes),SpatialPoints(particles2),byid=T),1,function(x) order(x,decreasing=F)[1:2]))

 #new plot of particles in red, close nodes in orange
 #notice some of the closest nodes are shared, so there are only 7 unique closest nodes for the 5 particles
 ggplot(data=nodes,aes(x=X,y=Y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_point(data=particles2,aes(x=V1,y=V2),col="red")+
  geom_point(data=nodes[closestnodes2,],aes(x=X,y=Y),col="orange")

 #new distances
 distances2 <- 
 cbind(apply(gDistance(SpatialPoints(nodes[closestnodes2[,1],]),                              
 SpatialPoints(particles2),byid=T),1,min),               
 apply(gDistance(SpatialPoints(nodes[closestnodes2[,2],]),
 SpatialPoints(particles2),byid=T),1,min))

         [,1]       [,2]
 1 0.05734493 0.05734493
 2 3.80414471 4.25678464
 3 0.83460359 1.81570764
 4 1.91783811 1.91783811
 5 2.05729381 2.05729381
```

Since my find distance command is just "compare all nodes to all particles and pick the minimum distance in the row," it messes up when the closest node to one particle is also the second closest node to another particle. The DF above shows me that particle 1 is .05 from its closest node, and .05 from its second closest node, which isn't true. It's just measuring to the same node twice. I need to rewrite the distances command to say "measure distance between this nodes list and this particles list in order of elements, not by min." Any help appreciated.